# What is the advantage in using CDN?

Tags: cdn

People often suggest CDNs for public library. The one I read today goes like this:

> It's recommended that production applications utilize CDNs for common
>   libraries like AngularJS
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/angular

Why it is recommended so?

One thing I can think of is, since the content comes from different domain, the browser specific limit for number of connections to a domain will not be a bottle-neck for loading scripts if multiple such libraries are being used. However, this can be solved by combining scripts.

Do you know any other benefits?

Comment: This seems like an easy question to find an answer to.

Comment: Using CDN has a lot of advantage. You get the latest updates automatically. You don't have to save the files on your own server. Visitors don't have to make more connections to your server to download the files. And there are many more, simply search on Google will lead you to some results.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you provided yourself is in-fact a good reason as to why you should use a CDN. Another reason which you overlooked and is dependent on how the CDN is structured is that, if the library gets updated, anyone using the CDN version will get the newest version with no hassle(obviously this wont work if you are referencing a file which has a version number directly i.e. jquery-1.3.2.js).